# How do I retrieve a numeric column from a database to my app

Tags: occi

I have an occi app and I want to retrieve values in a numeric column in a database. How do I retrieve the values?

There is a standard method from the occi, getNumber() for obtaining value of the attribute for Number object, but I am not sure the workaround of it.